# How json array pages by id dart

Tags: flutter, dart

how all pages to map title print? 
how json select example id=12 to map print title

```
{
  "result": {
    "name": "json1",
    "pages": [
      {
        "zones": [
          {
            "title": "title1"
          },
          {
            "title": "title2"
          }
        ],
        "id": 4
      },
      {
        "zones": [
          {
            "title": "title3"
          },
          {
            "title": "title4"
          }
        ],
        "id": 12
      }
    ],
    "creatorUserName": "admin",
    "id": 2
  }
}
```

```
                List post = json; 
                children: post
                .map( (post) => Container(
                        child: Center(child: Text(post.title]),) 
                      ))
                  .toList(),
```

Comment: Your code contains several syntax errors and it is not clear what you want to achieve. Can you write what output you expect and show us a full example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to map the json that you posted and print the titles to a list of containers? Couldn't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

I make a code to parse your json

```
var data = json.decode(jsonData);
var pagesArray = data["result"]["pages"];

pagesArray.forEach((page) {
  var zones = page["zones"];
  //Each id have your titles
  int id = page["id"];
  List<String> titles = new List();

  zones.forEach((zone) {
    titles.add(zone["title"]);
  });

  print("Id $id have this titles : ${titles.toString()}");
});
```